# Importing large set of numbers from a text file into python program in matrix form

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, point-clouds

I'm trying to import some pointcloud coordinates into python, the values are in a text file in this format

```
0.0054216 0.11349 0.040749   
-0.0017447 0.11425 0.041273  
-0.010661 0.11338 0.040916  
0.026422 0.11499 0.032623
```

and so on.
Ive tried doing it by 2 methods

```
def getValue(filename):       
    try:                                                                            
        file = open(filename,'r')  
    except: IOError:  
       print ('problem with file'), filename       
    value = []  
    for line in file:  
        value.append(float(line))  
    return value
```

I called the above code in idle but there is an error that says the string cannot be converted to float.

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genformtxt('co.txt', delimiter=',')
```

In this method when I call for data in idle it says data is not defined.

Below is the error message

```
>>> data[0:4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
data[0:4]
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you please format your question and code. Don't use numbers when formatting code as this will mess it up. Please also make sure all code indentation is exactly as it is on your machine

Comment: Sure, im sorry for the trouble im new at this

Comment: If you are getting "data is not defined" error then this has nothing to do with reading a file. You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you add the script you are using?

Comment: Im sorry to ask this question, but before executing `data[0:4]`, have you executed `data = np.genformtxt('co.txt', delimiter=',')`. Because it seems that your variable hasn't been created.

Comment: yes i did do that

Comment: It is working now when i put the path for 'co.txt', although i don't understand why it said data is not defined

Answer (score 0):

With the data you provided I would say you are trying to use:

```
np.loadtxt(<yourtxt.txt>, delimiter=" ")
```

In this case your delimiter should be blank space as can be seen in you data. This works perfectly for me.

Your problem is you are using the comma as delimiter.

Comment: Ive tried using space as well but the error does not seem to be because of this, the error says the name data is not defined

Comment: Using your same method (`genfromtxt`) works for me if I put delimiter as blank space...

Comment: Im sorry, but with the things you provided cant help you more, its working for me with the space... Good luck

Comment: @SarveshKumarMalladi The error has nothing to do with reading the data. You need to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry Im trying to add the error message Im still not comfortable with the formating, please bear with it

Answer (score 0):

`float()` converts one number string, not several (read its docs)

```
In [32]: line = '0.0054216 0.11349 0.040749 '
In [33]: float(line)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-0f93140abeab> in <module>()
----> 1 float(line)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.0054216 0.11349 0.040749 '
```

Note that the error tells us which string is giving it problems.

It works if we split the line into substrings and convert those individually.

```
In [34]: [float(x) for x in line.split()]
Out[34]: [0.0054216, 0.11349, 0.040749]
```

Similarly, `genfromtxt` needs to split the lines into proper substrings.  There aren't any `,` in your file, so clearly that's the wrong delimiter.  The default delimiter is white space, which works just fine in this case.

```
In [35]: data = np.genfromtxt([line])
In [36]: data
Out[36]: array([0.0054216, 0.11349  , 0.040749 ])
```

---

With the wrong delimiter it tries to convert the whole line to a float.  It can't (same reason as above), so it uses `np.nan` instead.

```
In [37]: data = np.genfromtxt([line], delimiter=',')
In [38]: data
Out[38]: array(nan)
```

Comment: I tried out what you suggested but it just tells me problem with file

Comment: do I import the entire file for your method?